# Pricing of databases in Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am a little bit confused about pricing for Data in Azure.
I found on one [MS Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20140427133420/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/02/14/announcing-reduced-pricing-on-sql-azure-and-new-100mb-database-option.aspx) that 50GB has a price of $125.

Missing part for me is, if I have needs only for a database in the cloud:

- Do I pay only the amount of $125?
- Or I have to pay separately for RAM, storage, processors and others parts which one server needed to operate?
- What is the story about the performance of an Azure database?
- Do all the databases have the same resources available to operate?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator

Comment: @JonSeigel Yes I saw that and that make me more confused. Crutial question is. Do we have additional costs if I need just one database ?

Comment: As I tried to reformat the question a bit, I found out the last two questions never got any answer. I would say they deserve a separate question on their own. It is a best practice for the SE sites to try to address only one problem per question. It's easier for the eye, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That blog is a bit old, so I don't know if everything is still accurate. In the Azure world things work very fast and information changes often.

Info from the [main Azure site](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/?currency-locale=en-us#header-4):

> **The prices are per database per month!**
>
> Database Size Price Per Database Per Month    Database Units (DU) that
>   will appear on your Bill Greater than 10 GB to 50 GB  $45.954 for
>   first 10 GB, $1.996 for each additional GB
>
> 4.6 DU for first 10 GB
>   0.2 DU for each additional GB

That means that if you have a single database that's under 50 GB (and higher than the previous category of 10 gb), you'll pay 125$ per month while the database is online.

Comment: No additional costs for, bentwhit, storage or server ?

Comment: Nope, if you don't do anything else. Everything is included in the db server payment. Only if you use other Azure storage, or web site stored on Azure, you'll pay bandwidth and storage.

Comment: There is new info (still in preview) http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/ about three plan types (basic, standard, premium) and there different backup plans (basic= same day, standard = 7 days, premium = 30 days) you can restore to any point in that window. for the new price plans you can choose a performance level. standard S1 will cost 20 dollar s2 100 dollar.